# Prepared statement giving error

Tags: php, prepared-statement

What am I missing?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$name = 'Samuel "L" Jackson';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test2 (id, name) VALUES (?,  
?)");
$stmt->bind_param("is",'600' , $name);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm getting the following error:
Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C.... on line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind_param` accepts two or more arguments. The first must be a string identifying the data types for the SQL parameters. [The rest of the arguments must be variables that can be passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). `'600'` is a constant, so you cannot pass it by reference.

Just use a temporary variable to work around that limitation, like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$id = 600;
$name = 'Samuel "L" Jackson';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test2 (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $name);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Also how to write this in a prepared statement? return(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`name`) FROM `test2` WHERE `name` = '$name'"), 0) == 0 ) ? false : true;

Comment: You can't do a prepared statement in a one-liner like this using the standard MySQLi functions. You would need a wrapper library of some sort. Besides, this is hard to read; you are better off breaking it into a few lines, anyway.